# View emails on webpage with PHP

Tags: php, email

i am trying to create a backend system for all of my clients. Now in this backend you can do alot of things to manipulate the site but i also want to make sure that my clients can manage their day to day jobs. For this ive created a calender where they can create Events and such.

Now i wish to make sure that they can view their site emails directly in the backend

Now my question is in two parts

1. is it possible to view mails directly on a website
2. are there any plugins i can use to achieve it or any smooth way to do it?

Comment: How are they viewing their emails now? And are emails generated by a PHP script?

Comment: I was thinking that i would get the emails from php put them in an array and then render them in my view

Comment: Taking a look to http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.remote.mail.php must be a good beginning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your clients are receiving their emails on you web site like client1@yoursite.com, yes you can download and read emails  using PHP,  IMAP functions.

It is very easy to use. you have more detail from these tutorials.

http://www.sitepoint.com/exploring-phps-imap-library-1/

http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap